# Cmd+Shift+G not working; "Go to Folder" menu missing

Tags: macos, finder, shortcut

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is not working in Monterey 12.5. **Go to Folder...** does not appear in the **Finder** > **Go** menu.  All I get is an "alert tone" when I do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

No conflicts in other shortcuts and no tricky software installed on this machine (Mac Mini M1). I created a test user account and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> worked but the popup screen disappeared immediately.

All other <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcuts working-—just not <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Any advice?

Comment: Try Shift+Command+G

Comment: Check it hasn't been disabled. Terminal `defaults read com.apple.finder ProhibitGoToFolder` will show 1 if it's been disabled, 0 if it hasn't.

Comment: Based on that intel, it is disabled. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

From comments, it appears that `defaults read com.apple.finder ProhibitGoToFolder` has been set to 1 = disabled.

To reset it, type
`defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitGoToFolder -bool false`
then
`killall finder`

Answer (score 0):

Go into safe mode and try doing the same.
In case it's working fine in safe mode, that's one of your settings or installed apps that's causing the issue.

On a side note, you can install karabiner elements and use the even viewer there to check what your system is recognizing for the cmd+shift+g press (it might be different than what you think).